# Rails: map nested attribute to model's object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
# models
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :b

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :a

# controllers
class aController < ApplicationController
    def a_with_b
        @a_with_b = A.find(1, :include => [:b])
        puts @a_with_b # => #<A id:1> // `b` not mapped to `@a_with_b`
        puts @a_with_b.b # => [#<B id:1>, #<B id:2>] // still there's `b`
    end
end
```

Question:
 How can `b` be mapped to `@a_with_b`? 
 Expected:

```
puts @a_with_b # => #<A id:1 b:[#<B id:1>, #<B id:2>] >
```

The actual reason for all written above is to be able to get serialized object with the appropriate structure:
e.g.

```
{something: true, nothing: false, a: @a_with_b}.to_xml # =>

<xml>
  <something>true</something>
  <nothing>false</nothing>
  <a>
    <id>1</id>
    <bs>
      <b> <id>1</id> </b>
      <b> <id>2</id> </b>
    </bs>
  </a>
<xml>
```

Rails v.2.3

Comment: It may simply be that #inspect for AR classes does not show association data, whether loaded or not. You could test that by performing an update to one of those b records after the 1st `puts` and before the 2nd `puts`. If you don't see the update in the 2nd output, that means it must have been previously loaded and not lazily loaded.

Comment: Is there a practical problem you are trying to solve (where you need the `b`, but they aren't there) or do you merely want to understand what is happening and why the `puts` differ?

Comment: @Confusion, yes there's a small one. Need to sent serialized `@a_with_b` to front end. `@a_with_b` should be like the "expected one "in my post. Sending both `a` and `b` separately would not work in my case. I know i may create new hash with all the needed things in it but i was looking for "railsway" to handle this;

Comment: @ted, could you please update the question to reflect that the question was really about serialization initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serialize the data in JSON, you can do it like this:

```
@a_with_b = A.find(1, :include => [:b])
puts @a_with_b.to_json(:include => [:b]) # return a JSON encoded string
puts @a_with_b.as_json(:include => [:b]) # return a Hash
```

Answer (score 0):

I just spent some time poking around in the implementation of this, and it looks like what happens is the data is pulled from the database, and put into the activerecord object cache, such that if you reference them, it won't require a database query.  The objects do *not* end up nested in the way it seems you want, but I can't think of a reason this should be a problem.

In other words, unless you see that the SQL query being generated doesn't meet your expectations, this is probably the desired behavior.

Comment: OK. Is there any "railsway" to push that `b` inside of `a`?

Comment: Why do you need that?  If you tell us that, we can probably help with the larger problem.  Until then, it's hard to know what you want.

Comment: Can you, please, have a look at a comment of mine for the answer to Confusion?

Comment: Thanks, still i wonder how to map some value to ActiveRecord's model object